# ServiceStack QueryBase class for Paging + Sorting, but Validation not fired

Tags: servicestack

I've created a QueryBase class in order to support Paging and Sorting when needed.

```
public class QueryBase
{
    public string Sort { get; set; }
    public int PageNumber { get; set; }
    public int PageSize { get; set; }
}
```

If a class supports these features, it'll simply extend it like this:

```
public class Cars: QueryBase, IReturn<CarsResponse>
{
}

public class CarsResponse : IHasResponseStatus
{
    public List<Car> Cars { get; set; }
    public ResponseStatus ResponseStatus { get; set; }
}
```

Then in order to fill QueryBase from querystring I've created a RequestFilterAttribute that can be used when needed:

```
public class QueryRequestFilterAttribute : Attribute, IHasRequestFilter
{
    #region IHasRequestFilter Members

    public IHasRequestFilter Copy()
    {
        return this;
    }

    public int Priority
    {
        get { return -100; }
    }

    public void RequestFilter(IHttpRequest req, IHttpResponse res, object requestDto)
    {
        var request = requestDto as QueryBase;
        if (request == null) { return; }
        request.PageNumber = req.QueryString["pageNumber"].IsEmpty() ? 1 : int.Parse(req.QueryString["pageNumber"]);
        request.PageSize = req.QueryString["pageSize"].IsEmpty() ? 15 : int.Parse(req.QueryString["pageSize"]);
        request.Sort = req.QueryString["sort"].IsNullOrEmpty() ? "id" : req.QueryString["sort"];
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Everything is working properly, but my goal now is to enable Validation in order to define some basic rules like maxpagesize or minpagenumber.
A very basic implementation is:

```
public class QueryBaseValidator : AbstractValidator<QueryBase>
{
    public QueryBaseValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(query => query.PageSize).LessThanOrEqualTo(100).GreaterThan(0);
    }
}
```

In this way validator filter is not able to find the validator above in its cache, because it searches for Cars instead of QueryBase (line 11 ValidationFilter.cs):

```
ValidatorCache.GetValidator(req, requestDto.GetType());
```

What is the best solution for this problem in order to avoid writing same validation logic in each subclass?

Comment: I do not understand the need for the RequestFilter. Since you inherit from QueryBase - Cars already have the correct properties and therefore it is possible to use them as query parameters. The default values you supply in the filter could be set in the constructor instead. Right ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution but I don't know if it's the best one: using a validator for each class implementing QueryBase.

QueryBaseValidator modified as follows:

```
public class QueryBaseValidator<T> : AbstractValidator<T> where T : QueryBase
{
    public QueryBaseValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(query => query.PageSize).LessThanOrEqualTo(100).GreaterThan(0);
    }
}
```

Additional validator created for subclass Cars

```
public class CarsValidator : QueryBaseValidator<Cars>
{
}
```

In this way everything works and I've now a basic implementation of generic paging, sorting and very soon query with ServiceStack.

Comment: I added this as answer but the pattern used for paging is not the best one. I'll change it following suggestions from Demis

Comment: For FluentValidation, i think you have supplied the best answer, based on the project discussion: https://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/discussions/256596

Comment: @IvanFioravanti, Did you ever come up with a better method for paging?